# JS Get component position with neither GetElementById nor getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the position of a component without using GetElementById or getBoundingClientRect?

I'm using react/JSX to render components one inside of each other, and I'm trying to get the distance between the top of the parent and the bottom of the child, if I use that functions I need to wait until the child is rendered and I need to do the calculations on the parent

here is a sample code of what I'm doing

```
export function TestPage() {
  return <BaseObject />;
}

function BaseObject() {
  return (
    <div
      className="popBox"
      style={{ top: "100px", left: "100px", width: "500px", height: "500px" }}
    >
      <div
        className="popBox2"
        style={{ top: "150px", left: "150px", width: "200px", height: "200px" }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the css

```
.popBox
{
    background-color: #4F8989;
    position: sticky;
}

.popBox2
{
    background-color: #89694f;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `getBoundingClientRect`? You can place a React ref on the `div`s.

Comment: How can I use getBoundingClientRect with the ref? can you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: How are you trying to use getBoundingClientRect in your rect code? That would determine the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using the `useLayoutEffect` and `useRef` hooks to grab refs to the real DOM elements and querying their measurements.

```js
function BaseObject() {
  const ref1 = React.useRef();
  const ref2 = React.useRef();
  const [dump, setDump] = React.useState("");
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const el1 = ref1.current;
    const el2 = ref2.current;
    if(!(el1 && el2)) return;
    setDump(
      `${JSON.stringify(el1.getBoundingClientRect())}\n${JSON.stringify(el2.getBoundingClientRect())}`
    );
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {dump}
      <div
        className="popBox"
        ref={ref1}
        style={{
          top: "100px",
          left: "100px",
          width: "500px",
          height: "500px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="popBox2"
          ref={ref2}
          style={{
            top: "150px",
            left: "150px",
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<BaseObject />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.popBox {
  background-color: #4F8989;
  position: sticky;
}

.popBox2 {
  background-color: #89694f;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: It took me a moment because I've been rendering child components on a recursive function, but your code was a really good base that helped me a lot, thanks!